# Comparing size between polygons in different UTM zones

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon

I am going to compare size of different areas in Europe in different UTM zones. The areas I'm comparing are quite small (around 35-50 km2) and I was wondering how to do this the best way? Can I draw a polygon in one UTM zone and then move it to a different UTM zone to compare it with the polygon in the other zone? Most areas are within UTM 32N but I have some areas in UTM 29 and some in UTM 34.

The goal is to compare the size of each polygon compared to a reference zone in UTM 32.

Comment: What you are trying to do, is fundamentally wrong. It defeats the whole implementation of UTM system. If your points are outside your **projection** boundaries, that projection is not appropriate.

Comment: What is your goal? (1) Do you want  to examine how the change of a projection changes the area of the _same_ polygon? (2) Or do you already have some polygons which are distributed over Europe. You want to compare the size of the _different_ polygons. E.g. is polygon X (in Spain) greater than polygon Y (in Gemany)?

Comment: Why not just to take the areas of the geometries in their native UTM zones for comparison? But you must first define the maximum error that it acceptable because it can meant that UTM is not usable at all for you.

Comment: @Jens I want to compare the size of different polygon. E.g. polygon x in Spain greater than polygon Y in Germany. But I dont only want the actual measurements in number (cause then I could measure in the appropriate UTM for both places) I want to put one polygon into the other to compare the size visually.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment that refines your goal, I would rather suggest to project all your polygons in a single, equal area, coordinate system (e.g. Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area considering that you work in Europe), then you can shift your polygons for the comparison. Note that this projection will affect the shape of your polygons, but it should remain reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

it would be good to know more indepth about the work you'r trying to acomplish.

Different projections might give different areas even tho the polygons are the same. Using equal area projection should Always result in same area.

But here we go, yes you can draw a polygon. Create a new shape file as type polygon and edit its coordinate system to your liking. Then draw your polygon. Then "move it" to a different zone by using "Geoprocessing->ArcToolBox->Data Management Tools->Projections and Transformations->Project". In the Project window add the polygon you want to "move", and choose the coordinate system you want to "move" it to. Then click "ok".

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Please note, the most important factor in changing area size is not the zone number. It's rather a question of where the area is located within the respective zone. So the distance to the equidistant meridian is important when you copy the area to a different zone. Or do you only want to project it to a different zone without changing the location? Then the distance to neighbored zone (and the equidistant meridian) increases enormously.

Comment: I'll try to write down my goal more spesific. My goal is to compare an area zone in Dublin compared to an area zone in Oslo. I have drawn two polygons in the respective areas. And I want to visually compare the size of the two zones (which is represented by the polygons drawn around the zones), not only the actuall measurement in number.

Answer (score 0):

Due to projection issues this approach is not 100% exactly. See notes at the end.

Initial Situation:

- Feature class A: UTM 29N, showing polygon in Dublin
- Feature class B: UTM 32N, showing polygon in Oslo

I would try this to compare the polygons visually:

- Add Feature class A to data frame a.
  Coordinate system of data frame a is UTM 29N.
  Zoom to the polygon in Dublin.
- Add Feature class B to data frame b. Coordinate system of data frame b is UTM 32N. Zoom to the polygon in Oso.
- Switch to layout view. Add data frame a and b to layout. Set the same scale for both data frames.
- Place both data frame so that they overlie each other. Set background color of upper data frame to transparent.

Please note:

Due to the projection of the comparison is not exactly:

- Area: There is an  area distortion within each UTM zone. The area varies in east-west direction.
- Shape: There is a small distortion of larger shapes within the zone.